# ASP.NET Web API Upload Multipart MIME

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 and the codes is not working FileData and FormData is empty. I check the Post with firebug and it has the values.

My version of the nuget package is ASP.NET Web API 4.0.20710.0

I took the example from here "http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2"

See the images below

http://screencast.com/t/5fhj0CfgiG

http://screencast.com/t/KCsPizDmC

"http://screencast.com/t/hhGFGaSjV" ---> POST with image

When i use HttpContext.Current.Request i get the variables.

I test the application for framework 4.5 and works fine, i think maybe is a problem with framework 4.

I think could be my visual studio so i test it in another 3 pcs and i got the same issue.

Thanks

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    List<string> formData = new List<string>();

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    Collection<HttpContent> values = provider.Contents;

    // Read the form data and return an async task.
    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            {
                Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
            }

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                files.Add("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
                Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }

            // Show all the key-value pairs.
            foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
            {
                foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                {
                    formData.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
                }
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        });

    return task;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ReadAsMultiPartAsync provider FileData property does not have a value because it does not seem that you are posting any Binary data such as an image per your screenshot: [Post Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/KCsPizDmC). FileData will only have a value if you have an  on your webpage and of course browse and select a file to upload. The code you are using ironically is for the 4.0 .NET framework as the 4.5 framework uses the await and async keyword for async work. See this link for more info [MultipartFileData example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2). It seems that your issue may be the FormData.AllKeys. Not sure if that is is "extracting" your post data or not.